# Multiple subscribers for a Subject. Turns on when has subscriptions, else turns off

Tags: java, rx-java

I've been trying to find an elegant way to do this, but haven't been able to so far. There have been multiple times I wanted a design pattern for this, but haven't ever found anything sufficient.

Here is a use case: In Android, you can get GPS Location updates. Keeping the GPS on though is expensive. It's costly to have the GPS running, especially when you aren't doing anything with the location updates. I'd like to have a Subject / Observable that can have multiple subscriptions, that when it gets 1 Subscription, it gets and keeps the GPS on and starts streaming Location updates. When all subscriptions are unsubscribed, then it turns the GPS off.

What would be a good pattern for accomplishing this general behavior?

Comment: Are you aware of the [refCount](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Connectable-Observable-Operators#connectableobservablerefcount) operator?

Comment: @SamuelGruetter might be worth writing an answer up for, mine is too generic for this specific case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use the `share` operator, which is essentially the equivalent of `publish().refcount()`. I haven't tested to make sure it can resume, but the code seems to indicate that it could. Basically, it 'connects' to start the output when there is one subscriber, which is backed by only one subscription. Meanwhile it reference counts any other child subscribers, and when that goes down to zero, it unsubscribes the backing subscription. That means that you can hook into onSubscribe/onUnsubscribe **before** the `share` operator is called, and do what you need to with the GPS or whatever other thing needs to be pumping data. Pseudo-Java ahead:

```
public class GPSLocationManager {
    private final Observable<Location> locations;

    public GPSLocationManager() {
        locations = getMagicalGPSLocationObservable()
            .doOnSubscribe(() -> turnOnGps())
            .doOnUnsubscribe(() -> turnOffGps())
            .share();
    }

    public Observable<Location> getLocations() {
        return locations;
    }

}
```

Like I said, the open question mark seems to be whether, after you go down to 0, you can restart the connection. I believe the answer is yes, but I'm not positive.

Comment: This was the approach I had found that Samuel comments about above. I was specifically calling publish().refCount(), and if you look at the source code for share(), that's all it's doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

a form of reference count might be it, implemented as a proxy.
see [the proxy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern)

Essentially you wrap the service you want to expose, and open/close the actual service inside the proxy if the reference count is more than 0 / 0.

So your proxy keeps track of the number of times it has been opened. (all open connections to it's source). if the ref count is 0 then it turns GPS off.

This means that you can't have a true proxy though, as the end user will have to call open/close.
don't use finalize for this as this can lead to unforseen consequences. (don't trust on garbage collector for timing of your reference counter).

If you have to use the GPS interface purely (cannot extend it with open/close / addRef/removeRef) then you can also guess at it, and have each proxy keep a 'lastAccessed' timer which when expired, closes / drops it reference count and when activated increases the ref count again) However this will always be a tradeof (sometimes your code will wrongly guess it's not used)

anyways in all regards, the pattern to use would be proxy I suspect.

Comment: So reference counting is fine and all, and detecting new connections is easy, but how do I detect when things are unsubscribed and decrement the count?

Comment: As I tried to point out, you can't detect it. You either have to force the user to call a 'close' statement on your object or guess with some timeout and a timer that checks if there has been any activity since time T.

Comment: as you're using rxjava, have a look at the comment made by @SamuelGruetter . My solution is generic as I'm not familiar with rx-java but he seems to have found a solution for you.